# Visualforce map in apex:repeat rerendering bug

Tags: visualforce, map, rerender

We have a visualforce page that we embed into the contact details page to help users manage a contact's campaign members. I ran into the following error:

> Map key Test CR Default Status not found in map Error is in expression
>   '{!activeCRCamMap[pcm.campaign.Name]}' in page
>   campaignmembermanagement

I used the logic below to get around this error (found in other stackexchange posts).

```
public String activeCRCamPMapKeys {
    get {
        activeCRCamPMapKeys = '';

        for (String s : activeCRCamMap.keySet()) {
        // Use String.Value of since null is an expected key
            activeCRCamPMapKeys+=String.ValueOf(s);
        }

        return activeCRCamPMapKeys;
    }

    set;
}

<apex:tab>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!CONTAINS(activeCRCamPMapKeys, pcm.campaign.Name)}">
        <apex:repeat value="{!activeCRCamMap[pcm.campaign.Name]}" var="cm" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(activeCRCamMap[pcm.campaign.Name]))}">
            <!-- junk-->
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:tab>
```

The issue is that this only works sometimes.

We have a button that inactivates campaign members for the contact. When inactivating the last campaign member, the key is removed from the map (as it should be) upon re-rendering, we see this error. If the page is refreshed, the error does not display and we see what we expect to see.

I ran a test where I commented out entire the repeat block and hard coded a remove button with an ID. When clicking the remove button, the key is removed from the map and the button is no longer displayed (what I expect to see). It seems that the logic is working, but for some reason that I can't understand, VF is still parsing the code within the unrendered content and throwing the error.

**Summary:** Situation: the key exists when the page is loaded but is then removed from the map via a button. When rerendering I can see that the key is removed (good), the logic can see that the key is removed and the elements are not rendered (good), the apex:repeat element still contains a reference to the removed key and throws an error even though it will not be rendered (bad). Refresh the page and the error no longer occurs (good).

**Disclaimer:** I tried doing my best to explain the issue without pasting hundreds of lines of code. Please let me know if you have questions so I can update the post.

**Fix:** I do have a fix, if I remove "rerender" attribute from the button, it refreshes the entire page which allows VF to process the page correctly. This is really hacky (as it defaults to a different tab which require additional code to ensure that the user stays on the same tab). I'm just hoping there is a better fix (or maybe that I did something terribly wrong).

Comment: I could say there is an issue in rerendering the panel, you can do a separate POC and post the code here. like to see more relevant code